# How can I display an array list with Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Hi I have a multidimensional array and I need to display it in a list so my arry is like this one:

```
{"rut":["06152617-K"],"full_name":[""],"total_days":[30]}
```

I have my view like this:

```
<tbody>
     <tr v-for="post in posts">
       <td>{{ post.rut[0] }}</td></td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

if I add [0] or [index] it displays me an error so I wonder how can I display all the array values?

because if I remove and I just leave:

```
post.rut
```

It works but it does not displays anything

I am receiving this error:

```
Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
```

How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```json
     {
       rut:"06152617-K",
       full_name:"",
       total_days:30
     }
```

If you want to access this values you can do as you did before: `post.rut`

And if you wish to continue having array in object try this instead in html:

```html
    <tbody>
       <tr v-for="post in posts">
         <td v-for="(r,index) in post.rut">
           {{ r[index] }}
         </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Above code will loop over array of rut and create tds of array length